# Right-click randomly quickly hides menu

Tags: imac, mouse

I'm not figuring out what is causing this, but often when I right-click, the menu appears then quickly disappears... the time it takes seems random, I'm not finding anything consistent about it.

The same thing happens with other mice... is there some setting that determines this? I just want the menu to stay until I click something in it or click outside of it.

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 iMac i5

Any non-Apple mouse

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Please add your config (Device, Software, type of mouse, etc.)

Comment: @JBis I added config... do you know the solution or how to troubleshoot it now?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior if you *hold* the right mouse button, not just click it. It's so you can click and hold the right mouse button, move your mouse over the desired entry, and release to select. Make sure you're just clicking and not clicking and holding. It's possible it's a problem with the mouse itself sending the data incorrectly so your computer thinks the button is pressed down longer than it is.